# git-p4 -- any great explanations for how it works

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

If you use perforce remotely and desire to have the awesome speed of git for tracking diffs, here is the solution: http://kb.perforce.com/article/1417/git-p4

However, I've noticed the following:

1. Follow the instructions exactly
2. It can take a while to import a large tree without getting history
3. On a large tree, the first commit will take a long time as this command will sync the whole tree.
4. If you do a commit that you do not want to send to perforce, you have to do a "git rebase -i" and remove the offending commit record. You cannot do a "git p4 submit" and then "p4 revert" the file you don't want to send.
5. If you mess something up, things can get really confusing.

And that is my question. **Is there a good explanation of how git-p4 uses the remote repositories? And an overall explanation of hot git-p4 works?**

git-p4 is not for the faint-at-heart. I'm learning that you really need to understand git well in order to use it well.

Comment: I'd argue that you want to understand Git well in order to use it well, regardless of whether you're interfacing with perforce on the other side.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is some more information in `Documentation/git-p4.txt` in the git project source code.

git-p4 maintains a refs/remotes/p4 branch to mirror the remote Perforce server.
By default `git-p4 clone` and `git-p4 sync` update this remote and you rebase your master against it.

`git-p4 submit` requires configuring an additional local directory as the Perforce client root for use by `p4 submit`.

`git-p4 sync/clone`  will record each Perforce changelist number in the corresponding git commit message. For example:

`[git-p4: depot-paths = "//depot/test/": change = 51]`

Using these changelist notations, `git-p4 sync` acquires changelists on the Perforce server not yet committed to git, adding changelist notations to each new git commit message.

`git-p4 submit` begins by identifying new local git commits - those without `[git-p4: ...]`. 
Using the Perforce client local workspace, it syncs down the Perforce files, and with `git apply` applies the patches gotten from `git format-patch` on the unsubmitted git commits before calling `p4 submit`.

Then `git-p4 submit` calls `git-p4 sync` to update the ref/remotes/p4 branch against the just updated Perforce remote.

Finally `git-p4 submit` will call `git rebase` on the master branch against the updated remote. This results in the same git tree which was submitted, but with edited commit messages containing the `[git-p4...]` changelist notations.

> How does one keep a few files modified in git without ever sending them to p4?

`git-p4 submit` will submit all branch commits. Use the usual git tools to organize changes into and out of the branch you choose to submit to Perforce.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an answer to "What commits are pending to commit to perforce?" Any other "gotchas" with using this tool?

Comment: In my experience, any subsequent `git p4 sync` doesn't seem to be able to detect any new changes. For example, if I clone only the head and then run sync, it says "No changes to import!". To get new changes, I can run clone with the `@all` option, but this doesn't update the commit log messages

Answer (score 2):

I use git-p4 occasionally, as I travel frequently and don't always have a good connection to the office.  My understanding, although I've not dived into it deeply, is that git-p4 maintains a Perforce workspace for you.  Whenever you do a *git p4 rebase*, you're basically syncing code into your workspace, which git-p4 then replays as new commits into your git repository.  Whenever you do a *git p4 submit*, it replays a series of patches into your Perforce workspace and submits them using Perforce changelists.

I guess you can think of it as using a Perforce server as a remote branch, but realistically it's a very limited implementation of that.

If you have more detailed questions, I'd try posting on the Perforce forums.  There are a couple of folks in the office who have studied git-p4 in detail and might be able to help.

Comment: How does git-p4 know what is pending to submit to p4?

How does one modify the list of what will be submitted?

How does one keep a few files modified in git without ever sending them to p4?

Comment: I think the newer answer has more technical details, but the list of what is pending to submit is essentially the git commits on _master_ since the last time you ran _git p4 submit_.  You can modify what gets sent to Perforce by working in git branches and only rebasing onto _master_ what you want to send to Perforce.  You can keep files modified on other git branches without sending them to Perforce.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding "What commits are pending to commit to perforce?"

Any command that can accept a revision range (see [gitrevisions(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)) should work, you just have to refer to the p4 remote as an endpoint for the range.  For instance:

- `git log remotes/p4/master..master`
- `git diff remotes/p4/master..master`

I tend to use `show-branch` to get a quick overview of the state of my branches, in which case `git show-branch --all` works as well.

Answer (score 1):

First [`Documentation/git-p4.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-p4.txt) has changed quite a lot in 8 years: See the [diff between 2012 and Q1 2020](https://gist.github.com/VonC/a0a58d9fff3fba23967307c19151508e/revisions).

- you can specify a single commit or a range of commits on `git p4 submit`
- you can use `--shelve` and `--update-shelve` to shelve changes instead of submitting
- you can import labels from p4 into Git.
- you can export tags from Git as p4 label.

But regarding "how it works", there are now helpers:

- you have a **verbose** mode which will help you see what is going on
- you have a dry-run mode, which shows just what commits would be submitted to p4; do not change state in Git or p4.

And with Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), the usage is displayed.

See [commit 608e380](https://github.com/git/git/commit/608e380502f754b50ead6c7e6c3f5ff5ee8eca33), [commit e2aed5f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e2aed5fd5bfb0381a6f69373c01ef09d70467a5c) (16 Dec 2019) by [Ben Keene (`seraphire`)](https://github.com/seraphire).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bc85523](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc855232bcb14599890ddf8b97f7e94290f3a1f4), 02 Jan 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git-p4`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/608e380502f754b50ead6c7e6c3f5ff5ee8eca33): show detailed help when parsing options fail
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ben Keene</sup>
>
> When a user provides invalid parameters to `git-p4`, the program reports the failure but does not provide the correct command syntax.
>
> Add an exception handler to the command-line argument parser to display the command's specific command line parameter syntax when an exception is thrown.
> Rethrow the exception so the current behavior is retained.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you will find this alternative tool interesting:
http://lm1.github.io/git-p4s

This is a fork of the original git-p4 utility with support for Perforce streams however only one-way sync works at this point.